# How can I hide WordPress' horizontal Admin Bar, from logged in users, which appears at the top of page?

Tags: wordpress, hide

I currently run a WordPress website, which has adopted the Flatsome theme.

When someone is logged in, they are able to see the Admin Bar across the top of the screen.  How am I able to hide this Bar from anyone who is logged into the website?

Since I am not the Theme Author/Developer, I have created a Child Theme.  As such, I would like to be able to perform any suggested modifications, within the Child Theme's `functions.php` file

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'Header', do you mean the WordPress Admin Toolbar?  If so, this is how you can achieve your goal:

**Remove WordPress Admin Toolbar for all:**

Head into your Child Theme's `functions.php` file and enter:

```
show_admin_bar( false );
```

This will remove the WordPress Admin Toolbar, on all Front End pages, for everyone.

**Remove WordPress Admin Toolbar for selected users:**

You can also remove the WordPress Admin Toolbar, for specific users only.  If you would like to do this, one option is to enter the following code within the same `functions.php`:

```
if ( ! current_user_can( 'create_sites' ) ) {
    show_admin_bar( false );
}
```

What the above code is saying:

**Line 1:**  If current user can create sites on the network ...

**Line 2:**  ... Show WordPress Admin Toolbar?  False (ie ... No!)

Using this code as a template, you can modify it to remove the Toolbar, based on specific users.

To do this, head over to WordPress' [Roles and Capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Roles) resource.  Identify the relevant Role/Capability.  For example, `activate_plugins`, `update_core` and `delete_posts` etc.

Replace the `create_sites` entry, with your desired Role/Capability.  It is as simple as that.

Needless to say, if you change `false` to `true`, it will show the Admin Toolbar, for that Role/Capability.  This may be useful, if you want to remove the Toolbar for all *except* for a handful of Roles :-)

**Additional useful resource:**  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can